# Trying to update a property in an object inside array of arrays mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have an object inside an array that's inside another array...
how can i update the "points" property of a certain player by his id?
[db structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJexJ.jpg)

tried this but it doesen't work...

```
 let h2h=await H2h.find({"players.$.id":req.params.id})
 let h2h = await H2h.updateMany(
   { "players.$.id": req.params.id},
   { $set: { "players.$": user} },
   {
     new: true,
   }
 );
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does it raise an error? Does it modify something but not the value you want?

Comment: it doesent work, i.e no property in the object is updated... i guess because i havent located the right position of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually wanted to update the 'name' property (the 'points' was a mistake)
the correct answer is:

```
 let h2h=await H2h.updateMany(
//this line targets the element inside the array thats inside another array
    {"players":{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{id:req.params.id}}}},
//this line sets the 'name' property inside the unnamed array thats inside the players array
    { $set: { "players.$[].$[elem].name": user.nickName } },
//this line is for mongo to update only the element that matches the user's id
    {arrayFilters:[{'elem.id':req.params.id}]},
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need that first `let h2h = await H2h.find(.....` as you already 'find and update' the document in the `updateMany` method.

To update the property `points` for a particular player, you were really close to the solution, `numberOfPointsGiven` being the number you want to update it with:

```
let h2h = await H2h.updateMany(
   { "players.$.id": req.params.id},
   { $set: { "players.$.points": numberOfPointsGiven} }
 );
```

Keep in mind that `updateMany` will **NOT** return the newly edited object, as it differs from the `findByIdAndX` and `findOneAndX`. It instead returns a query indicating how many document have been updated, among other things. Please read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany)